# Is there a word for $\left\lfloor\frac{x-1}{n}\right\rfloor + 1$?

Tags: combinatorics, terminology, ceiling-and-floor-functions

I'm wondering if there is a name for this quantity

$$k=\left\lfloor\frac{x-1}n\right\rfloor+1=\left\lceil\frac xn\right\rceil$$

It represents the number of boxes needed to contain $x$ objects if each box can hold up to $n$ objects. Equivalently, $kn$ is the smallest multiple of $n$ which is greater than or equal to $x$. I'm sure there are many other uses for this quantity, and I seem to run into it a lot. I've tried searching for it but haven't had any luck.

Comment: With your equivalent definition, I think you can write it more succinctly as $$k = \left\lceil\frac{x}{n}\right\rceil.$$ So, "ceil of $x/n$" can work, if you count as valid.

Comment: @AryamanMaithani I encourage you to post that as an answer, so OP can accept it if they are satisfied.

Comment: @MikeEarnest: Thanks, have done that. I didn't do so originally because I wasn't sure if I'd count it as valid myself. :-)

Comment: Note that this simpler form is correct in a broader sense: when $x$ is not an integer it still satisfies your condition (number of boxes needed to contain $x$ objects), but the $x-1$ formula might be off by one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your equivalent definition, you can write it more succinctly as
$$k = \left\lceil\frac{x}{n}\right\rceil.$$
(Since $kn$ is the smallest multiple of $n$ which is at least $x$ $\iff$ $k$ is the smallest integer $\geqslant x/n$.)

So, "ceil of $x/n$" can work, if you count that as valid.

Comment: If there were an actual name for this quantity, that would be preferable, but I think this may be the next best thing.

Comment: Ok, I've unaccepted it for now, and will re-accept later if there are no better answers.